React Native Android TextInput | Error: Element type is invalid: Check the render method of 'InternalTextInput'
I am currently stuck on an odd bug in my react native app.
The bug only happens on android.
Basically, whenever I go to a screen on my app with a TextInput it crashes with the following stack trace.
——
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of InternalTextInput.
This error is located at:
in InternalTextInput (created by TextInput)
in TextInput (created by Review)
——
Again, everything works fine on IOS, it only happens on android.
Everything else in the app works fine, every other component i import from react-native works without issue.
React native version:  "0.71.16"



Any help would be appreciated.
I expected the textinput to import/render without issue.

I figuired out the issue. I was accidentally using Platform.OS = 'ios' in a component instead of Platform.OS === 'ios'. That was causing the issue.
